Why does TypeScript allow instances of classes not listed in a class array to pass type checks?
I’m encountering an issue with TypeScript where I want to restrict a function to accept only instances of specific classes defined in an array. Here’s my setup:
class Types { }
class T1 extends Types { }
class T2 extends Types { }
class T3 extends Types { }
class T4 extends Types { }
class T5 extends Types { }
class N1 extends Types { }
class NN { }
const types = [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]
function test(type: InstanceType<typeof types[number]>) { }

test(T1)       // ERROR: T1 is a class, not an instance.
test(T2)       // ERROR: T2 is a class, not an instance.
test(N1)       // ERROR: N1 is a class, not an instance.
test(NN)       // ERROR: NN is a class, not an instance.
test(new NN()) // ERROR: Instance of NN, which is not in the types array.

test(new N1()) // ERROR: Instance of N1, which is not in the types array.
test(new T1()) // OK: Instance of T1, which is in the types array.

Issue: The function test should only accept instances of classes from the types array (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5). However, TypeScript does not enforce this restriction correctly. Instances of N1 and other classes not in the array are being accepted.
Question: Why does TypeScript allow instances of classes not listed in the types array to be accepted? How can I enforce that test only accepts instances of the classes specifically listed in the types array?
Difference from Similar Questions:

My issue is specific to using InstanceType<typeof types[number]> to restrict valid instances based on a predefined list.

Similar questions I’ve seen generally discuss broader type compatibility or class instance type checks but do not address the specific use case of enforcing restrictions based on an array of class constructors.


...

Empty classes behave strangely, don't use them.  Add structure and the problem goes away

I understand your point, but even if I add a structure to the Types class, TypeScript still considers N1 to be valid, despite it not being part of the types array. because N! extends Types but is not part of array types.

Add structure everywhere you need distinct types

The reason you aren't getting errors is that all your your classes are empty objects. An empty object will match with every non-null type. This is because typescript compares types by their structure, not by their name. For example, typescript doesn't check that the type is named T1, it checks that it has all the properties which T1 requires. If T1 has no properties, then every type has the properties which T1 requires.
Add properties in and you'll start getting the expected errors.
class Types { 
    a!: string;
}
class T1 extends Types { 
    b!: string;
}
class T2 extends Types { 
    c!: number;
}
class T3 extends Types { 
    d!: boolean;
}
class T4 extends Types { 
    e!: boolean;
}
class T5 extends Types { 
    f!: null
}
class N1 extends Types { 
    g!: { hello: 'world' }
}
class NN { 
    baz!: () => void;
}

Playground link

With this approach, N1 will still be accepted because it extends Types, even though it is not in the types array.

Depends on the contents of the classes. An early version of my answer neglected to add properties to T1 through T5, which meant that N1 was compatible with them. In the latest version of my answer they're incompatible.
